# How to ignore a TSQL Where condition when the value of a filter is null in one statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, isnull, case-when

How to ignore a where condition when the value of a filter is null in one statement?

```
-- if @filter1LowerBound is null then
select * from MyTable

-- if @filter1LowerBound is not null then
select * from MyTable
where column1 > @filter1LowerBound
```

Would that be possible to write one single where condition to handle the above situations?

I know I can `CASE WHEN` statement when my column is using "=".

or like:

```
select * from MyTable
where column1 = ISNULL(@filter1LowerBound, column1)
```

But I am having greater than and less than operators.

I have more greater than and less than filters like that so I'd need to make it work.

How would that be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
select * from MyTable where 
   (@filter1LowerBound is null or column1 > @filter1LowerBound)
```

Comment: Isn't this just a copy of Bort's answer?

Comment: @Abir yes and no, its the same answer, both of us posted at roughly the same time, with Bort clicking it before the minute mark and me after

Answer (score 5):

One way is to combine the clauses like so:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE (@filter1LowBound IS NULL OR column1 > @filter1LowerBound)
   -- AND other conditions here
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming column1 is numeric

```
select * from MyTable where column1 > ISNULL(@filter1LowerBound, column1-1)
select * from MyTable where column1 < ISNULL(@filter1LowerBound, column1+1)
```

Similarly, if it's a string

```
select * from MyTable where column1 > ISNULL(@filter1LowerBound, '')
```

etc